# Eulerian path, arranging words

Tags: algorithm, graph

There is a large number of magnetic plates on every door. Every plate has one word written on it. The plates must be arranged into a sequence in such a way that every word begins with the same letter as the previous word ends. For example, the word acm'' can be followed by the word
motorola''.

Eg:
skenzo
logicboxes
orderbox

ans: ordering possible

I know this problem is related to Eulerian path. But I am unable to implement it. Can someone tell me how it can be implemented. Means how should I make graph and which nodes must be connected. I know I have to use adjacency matrix but which nodes must be connected.

Comment: Why should I accept an answer if it isn't satisfying or correct?

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you accept unsatisfying or incorrect answers. When I wrote that comment, you had 10 questions, 8 with answers, and no accepts. That tends to discourage people from answering new questions from you. I see that you now have accepted a couple of answers, which helps you (with a little rep boost) and the community (which can see what answers worked).

Comment: yeah spoj ques.. but interesting one

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but aren't you looking for a **Hamiltonian** path (each word visited exactly once) rather than an Eulerian path (each edge visited exactly once)?

Comment: Depends on what you call edges, what you call nodes.  For example, if there is one node per letter, the set of words is the set of edges.  Alternately, treat the words as nodes, and for each word add edges from its end letter to matching start letters of other words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WORDS1, if I remember correctly. Contrary to some others, I agree that what you want is an Eulerian path, not a Hamiltonian. In the resulting graph, the words are the edges (from first letter to last) and the letters (conveniently only lower case letters from 'a' to 'z' in ASCII) the vertices.

Actually, what you want is not the path itself, you only want to know if there is one. So you need necessary and sufficient conditions on a graph for the existence of an Eulerian path.

Evidently, for such a path to exist, the graph has to be connected. You can determine that efficiently with a *union find*.
Then, the existence of such a path imposes conditions on the in- and outdegrees of the vertices. If you formulate these conditions correctly, a) they are necessary and sufficient, b) they are easy to check.

It's more fun to find the conditions yourself, but you could also find them in the wikipedia article about Eulerian paths.

Comment: I am unable to understand why the letters should be vertices. Can you please give a small example? Solutions are available for the program, but dunno why the concept is not getting in my mind. What I thought was suppose the word is 'acm' and another word is 'moto' then acm is connected to moto in a directed graph. Please can you clarify.

Comment: Each word is an edge from its first letter to its last, `recent ~> (r->t)`, `radar ~> (r->r)`, for example. So you start with a graph with 26 vertices and no edges, add edges as they come. When all edges are recorded, you throw away all vertices with no incident edges. That's the graph you have to investigate.

Comment: graph shud be directed or undirected?

Comment: @SurayansTiwari Directed. Each word is an edge _from_ its first letter _to_ its last.

Answer (score 0):

Ascii codes of first and last symbols can be used as graph vertices. You can try to use DFS for vertices ordering and than check if all vertices was ordered. If so than all words can be arranged with that order.