# Checking if Hamiltonian path exists

Tags: algorithm, hamiltonian-path

I am trying so solve interesting algorithmic problem, I would say, and after unsuccessfully trying bunch of various stuff, I am looking for help here.

So here is the assignment:
Suppose we have magnetic board and magnets with words on it. We want to make sequence of **all** these words so that the last letter of first word is the starting letter of the next word. It's like word chain game.
For example for words "car", "gear", "rig", "rez" the sequence would be as following: car -> rig -> gear -> rez.
Now the output of this program for given set of words is only true (words can be arranged in such way) or false. There is no need to return the specific path.

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve this puzzle? I suppose creating graph and finding the Hamiltonian path is the way, but the problem is that finding Hamiltonian path is way too complex problem that will take too long for bigger input.

Thank you very much for any help

Jan

Comment: You can exit early if there is a starting letter with no matching ending letter and vice versa

Comment: Well if this happens, It does not necessarily means that I have to exit. In my example there is word car with starting letter 'c' with no matcing ending letter, but because I have put it on the very beginning of the sequence, it is still valid solution.

Comment: True, should be two misses then.

Comment: This is an *Eulerian* path problem, not a Hamiltonian one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698190/eulerian-path-arranging-words

Comment: I was waiting for this comment :-D. Many people confuse this, but this is Hamiltonian path. In Eulerian, you have to visit each edge once.  In this problem, you have to visit each vertex once. But it depends on how you look at the graph. If you want the words to be edges, that we will have Eulerian problem.

Comment: So, you question is how to find the hamiltonion path? This is an NP problem, so just brute force it if you want a generic solution.  Otherwise check wiki, there are some more efficient methods out there if the graph has certian requirements. 
But maybe better to follow the comments and restructure your graph where the words are the edges, than you can find the Eulerian path.

Comment: Well, at first I thought about it as the Hamiltonian path. But the key is, as you stated, to pick different structure and actually look for Eulerian path.